# filtering packets from pcap file

Tags: c++, pcap, libpcap, winpcap

I am new with the pcap library and I am building a program that loads pcap file and process it for my needs with `winpcap`.

this is part of my pseudo code:

```
pcap_file= pcap_open_offline(pcap_path, errbuff);

while ( !EOF )
{
    //read the next packet from pcap file
    pcap_next_ex(pcap_file, &header, &data);
    if ( the packet belongs to ETH->IP->UDP->RTP->H264 protocol)
        process_packet(header, data);
}
```

I found the function `pcap_compile()` but from my understanding this is for live capture.

Since I load pcap file offline I struggled to find similar filter function.

How can I filter packet that loaded from pcap file? The filter should pass only packets from the ETH->IP->UDP->RTP->H264 protocol.

Comment: It's not clear what your question is.

Comment: Hi. sorry if I didn't explain myself properly. how can I filter packet that loaded from pcap file? the filter should pass only packets from the  ETH->IP->UDP->RTP->H264 protocol

thanks.

Comment: As far as I can recall, pcap doesn't care whether it's a live capture or from an offline file, but I could be wrong. You should probably read their manual.

Comment: According to Guy Harris [here](https://www.mail-archive.com/tcpdump-workers@lists.tcpdump.org/msg01797.html): "pcap_setfilter() works on a pcap_t that you've opened with pcap_open_offline() the same way it works on a pcap_t you've opened with pcap_open_live()."

Answer (score 3):

> I found the function `pcap_compile()` but from my understanding this is for live capture.

No, it's for live capture *AND* reading from a savefile.

> The filter should pass only packets from the ETH->IP->UDP->RTP->H264 protocol.

No such filter is possible using `pcap_compile()`.

To identify RTP traffic, you'd either have to know what UDP ports would be used by the traffic, and filter based on that, or you'd have to look at a few fields in the UDP payload and try to *guess* whether it's RTP traffic (and be willing to live with *non*-RTP packets passing the filter).  Wireshark has a fairly weak heuristic to identify RTP running atop UDP; it is *not* enabled by default, because it's so weak that it would probably identify non-RTP traffic as being RTP traffic.

As for H.264, Wireshark recognizes that based on the SIP/SDP setup traffic, which means it involves more complicated packet parsing than can be done with a pcap filter *and*, more importantly, involves keeping state information, which is *impossible* with pcap filters.